# What's the meaning of Satyam Sivam Sundaram?

Tags: scripture, translation-request

What's the exact meaning of combo of these words in context of Hinduism? And what's the meaning of these words in general sense? Which Hindu text  has this sentence?

Comment: It means GOD is truth, truth is shiva and shiva is beautiful

Comment: It is the same as sat chit( light of consciousness) anandam (bliss). sat= real, eternal (to the exclusion of all else). The same as asti (is) bhAti(is effulgent) priyam (is blissful). asti= sat=satyam, bhAti=chit=sivam, priyam=anandam=sundaram

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure where these words are found but this article might help in interpreting the meaning:

> The nature of the Self is described as Satyam, Shivam, Sundaram:
>   Truth, Tranquillity and Innocence, and Beauty. Spirituality is a
>   journey from the outer world of names and forms to the subtle world of
>   energies, to the innermost core of our being, the Self.
>
> Satyam or Truth is multidimensional, unchanging in time and space. It
>   is the substratum, the basis of entire creation. Shivam is the
>   embodiment of calmness and tranquillity, innocence and benevolence.
>   Shiva is always mentioned along with Shakti. Shakti is the primordial
>   energy responsible for entire creation. Energy is the feminine aspect
>   and is addressed as Mother Divine, the Devi. Like the sea and the
>   waves, though seemingly separate, they are essentially the same. Like
>   the light and the lamp, dancer and the dance, Shiva and Shakti, the
>   creation and the creative impulse are inseparable. Sundaram is beauty.
>   We move from recognising beauty outside to beauty within. Adi
>   Shankaracharya in his composition Saundarya Lahiri (Waves of Beauty),
>   glorifies the incomparable beauty of the Divine Mother. Here he speaks
>   of Apangat or Kama, the god of love, an archer with a bow and five
>   flower arrows. When Apangat hits you with his arrow of flowers, a wave
>   of beauty is created inside you.
>
> The five flowers represent the five senses through which you
>   experience something that is beyond the senses. You experience a wave
>   of beauty rising deep inside you; you have dissolved into the
>   formless. Rather, you are formless. You have come back to your nature.
>
> When you look at beautiful scenery, your eyes shut and you sink into
>   that ocean of beauty. When you smell a fragrant flower, the flower
>   remains outside, the fragrance disappears in a void, and you drop into
>   being. That is beauty. When you hear beautiful music, you become fully
>   immersed in it and you no longer know what is being played. You are
>   lost in the formless divinity within.
>
> In this way, Adi Shankara has described the beautiful journey from the
>   gross to the subtle, the outer to the inner, the form to the formless,
>   and the limited to the infinite, non-dual consciousness.
>
> Established in such a state, you start appreciating everything from a
>   thorn to a snail and a sea urchin. Dispassion to one's Self,
>   dedication to society and devotion to God is the secret of undying
>   beauty. Without dispassion, beauty is short-lived.Possessiveness turns
>   beauty into a mirage. Devotion and wonderment is simply appreciating
>   beauty without possessiveness. You see a beautiful painting and you
>   want to own it, you want to take it home with you, but then you hang
>   it on your wall and after a while you don't even look at it. Adi
>   Shankaracharya was an embodiment of dispassion. He could fully cognise
>   and experience beauty in entire creation.
>
> Beauty creates a thrill; it wakes up the sleeping consciousness.
>   Beauty can also bring ecstasy and draw you into deep meditation.
>   Meditation is complete relaxation, like a cool shower for the mind. It
>   is the act of getting in touch with your own divinity, getting back to
>   your nature. Your nature is truth, innocence and beauty.
>
> To be able to perceive truth or beauty in creation, calmness is
>   essential. An agitated mind can neither see the truth nor appreciate
>   beauty. That's why Satyam, Shivam and Sundaram always go together. The
>   whole of Creation is nothing but 'Waves of Beauty'.

From an article by Bhanumati Narsimhan: http://www.artofliving.org/in-en/waves-beauty