# Where is the quote satyam shivam sundaram taken from?

Tags: shiva-purana

Satyam shivam sundaram where does this quote occur in scripture

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! This looks like a duplicate question of https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9539/647 . Please search on main sote before posting your question.